# NBG: paradox caused by non-example for class existence theorem

Tags: set-theory

The statement of class existence theorem includes "F be a formula that quantifies only over sets" then there exists a class A such that it contains only sets and a set x is in A iff F(x) is true.

I am curious to see an example which breakz this requirement and have a quantifier over classes, and what kind of paradox it causes.

I mean the requirement for the class A to contain only sets pretty much covers Russell's paradox of not belonging to itself. But why for quantifiers should be over sets only? What formula F will cause problems?

Comment: That requirement ensures that NBG is conservative over ZF. You can relax that requirement and still get a system which is free from all the paradoxes that we know about. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse–Kelley_set_theory.

Answer (score 4):

Allowing $F$ to quantify over classes doesn't "cause a problem" as such - rather, it results in a significantly stronger theory (called [$\mathsf{MK}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory)). There's nothing truly wrong with that, but one of the nice things about $\mathsf{NBG}$ is that it's a **conservative extension** of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. This means that any sentence about sets (as opposed to classes) which is $\mathsf{NBG}$-provable is already provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. The same is not true for $\mathsf{MK}$, though; for example, $\mathsf{MK}$ proves the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (and hence $\mathsf{NBG}$ too!). Essentially, there are certain technical contexts in which $\mathsf{NBG}$ is "extra-assumption-free" in a way $\mathsf{MK}$ isn't, and sometimes we care about that.

Comment: Winner! You typed your answer in quicker than I typed my comment to a similar effect! It's maybe worth adding that MK disposes with Russell's paradox (we hope), just by disallowing classes as members of other classes. In many ways, this is more natural than then NBG restriction on the quantifiers in predicates used to define classes.

Comment: 1) How limitation of size follows from allowing F to quantify over classes? 2) How M(X)<=>exists Y: X in Y is connected with axiom of limitation of size? 3) Is it correct to call statement like class existence theorem with dropped requirement of quantification over sets theorem an unrestricted comprehension?